# How can i add template context in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse , there are standard contexts for editors. For java editors, there are java , java statements, java type members...

Is there anyway to add new context in templates ?

[image: template view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add contexts but only by writing an Eclipse plugin. The `org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates` is used to do this with the `contextType` element.

For example the 'Java' context is defined using:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
  <contextType
        name="%templates.java.contextType.name"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaContextType"
        id="java"
        registryId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor">
  </contextType>
```

Comment: so it is not easy thing to add a special context :) ?